# Anyone happen to give a hand to solve issue with Solspace Ratings module?

Tags: channel, solspace-rating

I have a bit odd issue with Solspace Ratings Module.
It should hide the form after guest giving their review points but it keeps showing the form. Im on EE 2.10.1 running on php 5.6.2. No MSM, very basic installation. Ratings Module is the latest 3.3.1.
System folder is renamed and above webroot for extra info if that might count?

The form does get hide ONLY if you are logged in. But for guests, it just keeps showing up and worse, guests can submit as many reviews they want, even that form params are setup to allow only one vote.

Below is the setup for the form I have:

```
{exp:rating:form entry_id="{segment_3}" required="rating" anonymous="yes" collection="food-related" return="food/index" duplicate_check_guest_ip="no" allow_duplicates="no"}

{if not_duplicate}
<div class="heading-block"><h1><span>So, did you like this?</span></h1></div>
<p><b>1 = Didnt like. 5 = I want more!</b>, Tell us, please:<br>
<select name="rating" id="rating" class="required">
<option value="1">1 points</option>
<option value="2">2 points</option>
<option value="3">3 points</option>
<option value="4">4 points</option>
<option value="5">5 points</option>
</select></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" class="button button-3d button-small button-rounded button-red" /></p>
{/if}

{if duplicate}&nbsp;{/if}  
{/exp:rating:form}
```

Comment: Friend, does a guest user submission give you any JavaScript errors in the developer console? Does this module use Ajax or form POST for rating form submission?

Comment: regular action with return param, no js errors.

Comment: Are you testing locally or on a live site? Are you blocking cookies? Using a browser add-on that might affect cookies perhaps? Have you tried with another browser/computer? As Jim mentioned in the answers, try `duplicate_check_guest_ip="yes"` or removing this parameter. Finally, have you tried doing the same thing with the Demo Templates that come with Rating? (Worked for me)

Comment: I think I forget to allow guests from rating since I just can't figure out why it allows looping submit even what I've set.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

try removing this parameter.

```
duplicate_check_guest_ip="no"
```

Comment: No help with that.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the Preferences tab?

Check the member groups settings that are allowed to post ratings

### Check the Require email address for Guests?

My working code..

```
{exp:rating:form
collection="contest"
entry_id="{entry_id}"
allow_duplicates="no"
required="rating|email" 
anonymous="no"
return="{current_url}/rating-success/"
user_template="user_template"
form:class="validate" 
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Im using the form with anonymous="yes", and no email required. Also checked that guests can submit ratings, and require email is set to "no".

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions?

Comment: Yep. No success. Guests still can see the form after first submit, and can still submit as many ratings as they want.